# StringIndexOutOfBoundExceptions error is showing

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to make an acronym from the three words that is input by the user:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Acronym
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {    

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       String phrase;
       System.out.println("Please, enter the three words here>> ");
       phrase = input.nextLine();     
       char first, second, third;
       int stringLength;
       int x = 0;
       char c;
       stringLength = phrase.length();
       first = phrase.charAt(0);
       second = phrase.charAt(x + 1);
       third = phrase.charAt(x + 1);

          for( x = 0; x < stringLength; x++);
          {
             int a = 1;
             c = phrase.charAt(x);

             if(Character.isWhitespace(c));
               if( a <= 1)
                second = phrase.charAt(x+1);

             else if(a <= 2)
                third = phrase.charAt(x++);
          }

      System.out.println("The acronym is " + first + second + third);
   }

 }
```

But, whenever I try to input StringIndexOutOfBoundExceptions error is showing. For example I tried to input the three words "One Two Three" and this is the result:

Please, enter the words/phrases: 
One Two Three

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 13
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
    at Acronym.main(Acronym.java:23)

Comment: I have resolved the IndexOutOfBoundExceptions error by removing the semi-colon after the loop, thank you!
However, the result is OTn which is not my desired output. Since I input "One Two Three" I want the result to be "OTT." What should I do?

Comment: Your new problem is that you only ever assign `third` once, and that's at the line before the loop.  You've assigned it to the character after the initial `O`.  I'm not sure what your intention for the variable `a` is, but  you assign it to `1` and you never change it.  That means that your `else if` condition is never checked.  I would suggest that you move away from your computer for a few minutes and sketch out on paper what you want your program to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon

```
for (x = 0; x < stringLength; x++);
                                  ^
```

which is terminating the for loop. Same for the semi-colon terminating the `if` statement

```
if (Character.isWhitespace(c));
                              ^
```

and please use braces to surround control blocks

Comment: However, the result is OTn which is not my desired output. Since I input "One Two Three" I want the result to be "OTT." What should I do?

Comment: You could split the input line based on whitespace then easily output the first letter of each resulting String

Comment: I invite you to try it (hint: look at `String.split`). Come back if you get stuck and there will be plenty of `SO` users willing to answer sensible questions! ;)